# Javascript autocomplete function not work with spaces

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im have an autocomplete function searching in database field (name).

If my field = john, and i typing "joh" autocomplete works fine.
But
If my field = john marshall, and i typing "joh" or anything, autocomplete doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

my code:

index.php

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jqueryui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $( "#matricula" ).autocomplete({
                source: "searchalumno.php",
                minLength: 2
            });

            $("#matricula").focusout(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'alumno.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{ matricula:$('#matricula')}
                }).done(function(respuesta){
                    $("#nombre").val(respuesta.nombre);
                    $("#paterno").val(respuesta.paterno);
                    $("#materno").val(respuesta.materno);
                });
            });                         
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label for="matricula">Matricula:</label>
        <input type="text" id="matricula" name="matricula" value=""/>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value=""/>
        <label for="paterno">Paterno:</label>
        <input type="text" id="paterno" name="paterno" value=""/>
        <label for="materno">Materno:</label>
        <input type="text" id="materno" name="materno" value=""/>
    </form>
</body>
```

alumno.php:

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli('servidor','usuario','password','basedatos',3306);
$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
$consulta = "select nombre, paterno, materno FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula = '$matricula'";

$result = $conexion->query($consulta);

$respuesta = new stdClass();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $fila = $result->fetch_array();
    $respuesta->nombre = $fila['nombre'];
    $respuesta->paterno = $fila['paterno'];
    $respuesta->materno = $fila['materno'];     
}
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

?>

searchalumno:

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli('servidor','usuario','password','basedatos',3306);
$matricula = $_GET['term'];
$consulta = "select matricula FROM tblalumno WHERE matricula LIKE '%$matricula%'";

$result = $conexion->query($consulta);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($fila = $result->fetch_array()){
        $matriculas[] = $fila['matricula'];     
    }
    echo json_encode($matriculas);
}
?>
```

Comment: No prepared statement ? Just concatenating ? Are you aware there's a big security flaw here ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret comment is worth echoing.  You'll really want to read on SQL injection attacks and why you should never write/use code that takes raw user data.  That's how websites get hacked and taken over.

Comment: That said -- you need to start your own debugging.  Use your browser's console and look at the NETWORK tab.  Examine the data coming back and see if the error is on the JavaScript side or the PHP side.  See if there are any errors listed there.

Comment: @DenysSéguret  Yes, but Its a local lan application, without internet and risks. thanks.

Comment: @gmyb did you check if the sql query give you back the right results? or is a problem in the render side?

Comment: @gmyb Take it from years of experience.  "local lan applications" have a habit of growing into bigger things -- or code re-used without though.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request, use input value instead of input object:

```
  $.ajax({ ... data:{ matricula: $('#matricula').val() } })
```